# Target a div from multiple classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to target the div `#menu-separator` from multiple page classes `(.cms7, .cms8...)`

I tried that but it doesn't work:

```
    .cms7, .cms8, .cms9, .cms10, .cms11, .cms12, .cms13, .cms14, .cms15, .cms16, .cms17, .cms18, .cms19 #menu-separator{
background: white;
}
```

Is there a shorter/lighter way to do that?

Comment: There can be only one `#menu-separator` anyway so you can just do `#menu-separator { background: white; }`

Comment: If you absolutely must have it be a sub-element, you'll have to do `.cms7 #menu-separator, .cms8 #menu-separator...`. If this frustrating to you, consider learning LESS or SASS.

Comment: There is only one `#menu-separator` but I want to keep it red on some other pages like index, blog, contact...

Comment: Alright, then you have to do what @AlexMorrise says.

Comment: OK thanks guys, I'll do that. There will be no problem with a long CSS like that?

Comment: You could give all of them a common class and just use the one.

Comment: I'm afraid this is impossible... because it's a Prestashop website

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion to shorten your css:

```
[class^='cms'] #menu-separator {background: white;}
```

The above expression will cover all the classes starting with cms.

You can make it more restrictive, for example to cover all classes starting with cms1:

```
[class^='cms1'] #menu-separator {background: white;}
```

Comment: This definitely looks much cleaner. You'll sacrifice some rendering time but it'll be easier to maintain and read.